# Extract matrix from a system of linear equations

Tags: matrix

I have a big system of linear equations $f_i(x_1,...x_n)$ with $n$ variables and $n$ equations. I want to extract the matrix $M$ where $\vec{f}(\vec{x})=M\vec{x}$. For example if I have

$$
f_1(x) = x + 2y \\
f_2(x) = 3x-y
$$
then I want to get the matrix

> ```
> {{1,2}, {3,-1}}.
> ```

Is there a way to do this in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
l = {x + 2 y, 3 x - y};
Normal@CoefficientArrays[l, {x, y}][[2]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, -1}}

Comment: This is the convenient way to do it.  I got confused when looking at CoefficientArrays.

Comment: @Szabolcs Me too (blush)